Measurement bias of Hall sensors with moving permanent magnets
I want to measure the magnetic flux density produced by a moving permanent magnet.
In my case, the magnet would move left and right alternatively at speed of 10 mm/s, with a constant vertical distance from a 3-axis Hall sensor.
This magnetic sensor measures the magnetic flux density at a sampling rate of 500 Hz.
Would there be some measurement bias due to this changing (from the sensor point of view) magnetic field, like induced electromagnetic field, that would induce some error in the measured value compared to the "true" value ?
OR
Is it correct to consider each timestep as a static magnetic field problem ?
thanks !

Hall sensors are designed to measure the local magnetic flux density directly. They are not significantly affected by induced EMFs in the same way as inductive sensors or coils might be.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
